# How to create a string like "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? " in Scala?

Tags: string, scala

I want to definite a function like `createString`:

```
def createString(n: Int): String = {
    // do something here
    result = "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? " // thera are n "? " in result
    result
}
```

As I know, `["? "]*n` is the easy way in Python. But I don't know how to do it with Scala. What shoule I do?

Comment: From the duplicate, it looks like "multiplying" a string by a number works in Scala like in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can find your answer here

```
scala> List.fill(10)("? ") # Similar to ["? "] * n in Python                                                                                          
res0: List[String] = List("? ", "? ", "? ", "? ", "? ", "? ", "? ", "? ", "? ", "? ")
scala> "?, " * 10                                                                                                    
res1: String = "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
```

Comment: This is what I really want, Thank u!

Comment: In order to avoid the trailing `","`, you can use: `List.fill(10)("?").mkString(", ")`